# Fibonacci Sequence using Linked List crashes after linked list is destroyed. How can I trace the error?

Tags: c

I'm working on a program that calculates any number in the Fibonacci Sequence without using the int data type since it would overflow. Instead I am using linked lists to hold the digits that represent each number. My current issue is with freeing memory allocated to linked lists that I no longer need. If I'm calculating F(10000), I'd like the thousands of previous lists to be freed. The program as is produces each value up to "F(7) = 13" before crashing and showing "exit status -1". I'd really just like to know what's causing this error and go from there. Any help is appreciated. Thank you and I apologize for the large amount of code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node
{
int digit;
struct Node *next;
} Node;

typedef struct ListyInt
{
Node *head;
int length;
} ListyInt;



Node *create_node(unsigned int digit, ListyInt *listy);
Node *removeNode(Node *node, ListyInt *listy);
void listyPrintHelper(Node *current);
ListyInt *destroyListyInt(ListyInt *listy);
ListyInt *fib(unsigned int n);



void listyPrint(ListyInt *p)
{
if (p == NULL || p->head == NULL)
{
    printf("(null pointer)\n");
    return;
}

listyPrintHelper(p->head);
printf("\n");
}

void listyPrintHelper(Node *current)
{
if (current == NULL)
    return;

listyPrintHelper(current->next);
printf("%d", current->digit);
}

int main()
{
 int i;
 ListyInt *p;

for (i = 0; i <= 1000; i++)
{
    printf("F(%d) = ", i);
    listyPrint(p = fib(i));
    destroyListyInt(p);
}

 return 0;
}

ListyInt *listyAdd(ListyInt *p, ListyInt *q)
{
 ListyInt *listy = NULL;
 Node *ptemp = NULL;
 Node *qtemp = NULL;
 Node *temp = NULL;
 ListyInt *temp_list = NULL;
 unsigned int x = 0;
 unsigned int count = 0;

 if (p == NULL || q == NULL)
{
  return NULL;
}

 listy = malloc(sizeof(ListyInt));

 if (listy == NULL)
{
  return NULL;
}

listy->length = 0;

if (q->length > p->length)
{
temp_list = q;
q = p;
p = temp_list;
}

 while (count < p->length)
 {
  if (count == 0)
  {
  x = p->head->digit + q->head->digit;
  ptemp = p->head->next;
  qtemp = q->head->next;
  listy->head = create_node(x, listy);
  temp = listy->head;
  temp->next = create_node(0, listy);

  if (temp->digit > 9)
  {
    temp->digit = temp->digit - 10;
    temp->next->digit = temp->next->digit + 1;
   }
 }

else
{
  temp->next->next = create_node(0, listy);

  if (qtemp == NULL)
  {
    temp->next->digit += ptemp->digit;
    ptemp = ptemp->next;
    temp = temp->next;
  }

  else
  {
    x = ptemp->digit + qtemp->digit;
    temp->next->digit += x;

    if (temp->next->digit > 9)
    {
      temp->next->digit = temp->next->digit - 10;
      temp->next->next->digit = temp->next->next->digit + 1;
    }

    qtemp = qtemp->next;
    ptemp = ptemp->next;
    temp = temp->next;
   }
 }

 if (count == p->length - 1 && temp->next->digit == 0)
 {
   temp->next = removeNode(temp->next, listy);
 }

  count++;
 }

return listy;
}

ListyInt *destroyListyInt(ListyInt *listy)
{
  if (listy == NULL)
  {
    return NULL;
  }

Node *current = listy->head;
Node *temp;

while (current != NULL)
{
    temp = current->next;
    free(current);
    current = temp;
}

    free(listy);

return NULL;
}

ListyInt *fib(unsigned int n)
{
  ListyInt *spiral = malloc(sizeof(ListyInt));
  ListyInt *p = NULL;
  ListyInt *q = NULL;
  unsigned int count = 2;

  if (spiral == NULL)
  {
    return NULL;
  }

  if (n == 0)
  {
    spiral->head = create_node(0, spiral);
    return spiral;
  }

 if (n == 1)
 {
    spiral->head = create_node(1, spiral);
    return spiral;
 }

 p = malloc(sizeof(ListyInt));
 p->head = create_node(0, p);

 q = malloc(sizeof(ListyInt));
 q->head = create_node(1, q);

 while (count <= n)
 {
    spiral = listyAdd(p, q);
    destroyListyInt(p);
    p = q;
    q = spiral;
    count++;
  }

 return spiral;
}

Node *create_node(unsigned int digit, ListyInt *listy)
{
  if (listy == NULL)
  {
    return NULL;
  }

  Node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(Node));

  new_node->digit = digit;
  new_node->next = NULL;

  listy->length++;

  return new_node;
}

Node *removeNode(Node *node, ListyInt *listy)
{
  if (node == NULL)
  {
    return NULL;
  }

  if (listy == NULL)
  {
    return NULL;
  }

  free(node);
  node = NULL;
  listy->length--;
  return NULL;
}
```

Comment: `for (i = 0; i <= 1000; i++)
{
 ...
    destroyListyInt(p);
}` what did you mean by this?

Comment: ...and by this `while (count <= n)
 {
...
    destroyListyInt(p);
...
  }`

Comment: If the program crashed at F(7) that is not too hard to trace with a debugger, or by printing cues at every step. F(7) is 13, the **first two-digit term**, so it looks as if your scheme does not work at all. Strangely, the functions `removeNode` and `destroyListyInt` always return `NULL` for some reason.

Comment: I don't know how you manage to make it to seven iterations with the posted code. I can't get past the *first* real iteration (i.e. the third in the actual loop) due to a null pointer de-reference (`temp->next->digit += ptemp->digit`, where `ptemp` is null). And fyi, 250 lines of by-its-nature pointer jockeying deserves more than *zero* inline comments explaining what is going on.At this point a debugger is on your horizon.

Comment: Since you've got a full, reproducible, problem here, all in one file, you can just paste this code here:  https://www.onlinegdb.com/ , click debug, and type "run" at the gdb prompt.  It stopped me at well before 7 iterations.  At that point, maybe you'll need to hit up a gdb tutorial of some kind :)

Comment: Also, hopefully your formatting isn't this bad in your original source code.  If it is, definitely look into having it formatted.  Visual Studio can do it for you (ctrl-k,d usually), and various Linux editors have no shortage of plugins that can do the same.  If you don't, it will bite you in the ass, if it hasn't already

Comment: ...indeed it is hard to read where one function ends and the next starts.

Comment: I just want to echo the point about proper indentation. It is _really_ important that you learn to indent correctly (which is honestly pretty complicated, and something you tend to pick up over time). I'd suggest writing a fairly short piece of code with no indentation whatsoever, then taking it to your favorite IDE and running the autoindent, and seeing how it indents things, then mimicking that style. Play with the code and re-autoindent to see how it handles different situations. It's not perfect, but it'll help teach you an important skill.

Comment: If your indentation is fine in your original source, but you had to muck with it for Stack Overflow, you might be interested in `CTRL+K` -- highlight the text you want to format as code, press that (or `CMD+K` on Mac), and it'll automatically format it for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'd really just like to know what's causing this error and go from there.

Long story short, C's equivalent of a `NullPointerException`, as far as I can tell.

Long story longer, I haven't had time to fully examine your code or debug it, but I have had time to run it through [`gdb`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/), which is included with most Linux installations. If you're using Visual Studio, I vaguely remember there being a debug mode, which should show you roughly the same information, just in a different place. This is GDB's output:

```
Starting program: /home/ubuntu/C/a.out 
F(0) = 0
F(1) = 1
F(2) = 1
F(3) = 2
F(4) = 3
F(5) = 5
F(6) = 8
F(7) = 13

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004008db in listyAdd (p=0x6036a0, q=0x6036e0) at main.c:117
117         temp->next->digit += ptemp->digit;
```

(Okay, that's not *all* of it, but that's the relevant bit.)

What those last three lines mean is that you got a [segfault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault). There are a bunch of things that can cause it, but based on that line, it looks like it's been caused by trying to dereference an invalid pointer. That's either a `NULL` pointer (a value of `0x0`) or a pointer you've already `free`d.

If you're on Linux, you can then run [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) on it to figure out what, exactly, happened. It'll tell you if it's using a `free`d pointer or a `NULL` one, and that'll give you a good starting point to find the actual bug. You can also use your IDE's debugger (or GDB, if you want to try playing with the command-line version, but I wouldn't recommend it) to step through your program and see what the values of the variables involved are, which you can walk backwards from to see where they're being changed and invalidated.

If I had to guess, though, I'd say 0andriy's comments hit it on the nose -- you seem to be freeing things twice, and you probably meant to free them once, at the end.

I'm somewhat intentionally leaving this vague. Segfaults are common and (as you've noticed) difficult to debug, and you can only really learn how through experience. I think being shown the answer would honestly be less helpful than working through it yourself, and with tools like Valgrind and your debugger, that's not actually that hard, just tedious.

Comment: @PeterPrographo If you'll bother to read your answer, it was just a console output dump with no explanation. If you'll bother to read mine, yes, it's based on GDB as well -- except I (a) explained what tool I used, (b) explained what tool I would go on to use (and if I had access to Valgrind, which I don't, I'd add output from that as well) and (c) explained what the output means, instead of leaving it completely unexplained, like you did. Also, again, Be Nice. It's not exactly difficult to grasp. Blunt is fine; calling someone lame and talentless because they wrote a better answer is not.

Comment: And it is a better answer, for the record.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. It was because the length of my linked lists weren't being reset when fib() was called. Thanks for your help everyone.